# exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid Block Type: Mage_Bannerslider_Block_Bannerslider'

Tags: database

I'm new to Magento. And my task is to migrate magento online store to a subdomain for a development work.

1. Backed up the whole store
2. Backed up the database and import it in the new one I've created
3. I've changed the core_config_data values (URL)
4. Chnaged the .htaaccess which is pointing to the old domain
5. Changed the local.xml in app/etc/local.xml

So far everything is okay. But I get the error on the screen when I type the domain and It says: `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'lorotrad_elmaira_dev.sofia_slides' doesn't exist`
And in my exception.log I get the following thing:

```
2015-01-21T21:03:48+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Невалиден блок тип: Mage_Bannerslider_Block_Bannerslider' in /home/lorotrad/public_html/dev/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /home/lorotrad/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('???????????????...')
#1 /home/lorotrad/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('bannerslider/ba...', Array)
#2 /home/lorotrad/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('bannerslider/ba...', 'slide-show')
#3 /home/lorotrad/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('bannerslider/ba...', 'slide-show')
#4 /home/lorotrad/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/lorotrad/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/lorotrad/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /home/lorotrad/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /home/lorotrad/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'sofia_home_1col')
#9 /home/lorotrad/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'sofia_home_1col')
#10 /home/lorotrad/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#11 /home/lorotrad/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#12 /home/lorotrad/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /home/lorotrad/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /home/lorotrad/public_html/dev/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /home/lorotrad/public_html/dev/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

As I said I'm newbiew to Magento, but the most logicfull is that these same files and database are working on the other domain with no problem, no errors. So I'm just wondering where is the problem. If you need more information about this issue I'll provide it!

I need help guys.
Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Have you cleared var/cache folder after you changed website domain? You also should check that correct URL is set in core_config_data table for web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url **before** you flush cache.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And Yes. Firstly I changed the Secure and Unsecured URL and after that I cleaned the cache and session directories + browser cache(sometimes causes problems) but non of them helps.

Comment: Thanks for update! Is the database name 'lorotrad_elmaira_dev' used in app/etc/local.xml, and is table 'sofia_slides' present in both original and duplicate ddatabases?

Comment: Yes. The name of the database that it's written in the app/etc/local.xml is "lorotrad_elmaira_dev" and about "sofia_slides"... I found no tables at all with such name in the database, I have no idea what is it. May be some view which is not passed corectly. I realized that the website backup may contain corrupted files, corrupted during the uploading with FileZila and I reuploaded the whole 'app' folder. But no result.
Thank you for the anwser. If you need some additional information, I would post it.

Comment: Could you check the 'core_resource' table for %Bannerslider% records? It might be, that this module was installed, and then partially removed, and some leftover code is causing this exception.

Comment: Hi again. I accept that this is possible but I got no 'Bannerslider' in the 'core_resource' table. I checked the "/public_html/elmaira/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout" for 'Bannerslider' file but no result. After I searched, there is no bannerslider files in my website backup at all. So I might be wrong or the error is somewhere else...

Comment: I found the actual folder which has a mysql file with alot of statements in there. One of them was create table "sofia_slides", but I'm not sure why this isn't happening...
Do not know how to proceed...

Comment: Where was this file located and how is it named? It could happen that this file is complete or partial DB dump, but not Magento's extension DB update file.

Comment: I solved it, I just found the structure of all the tables that magento asked me to add and I added them so all went well. But I'm continuing with different issues. :)
Thanks for the time and effort!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear that you've solved this issue :)